# Saving a ObjectContext depended object after two requests (EF/MVC 3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Using EntityFramework, I am trying the following in combination with MVC 3.

I have a `ObjectContext`, which is being initialized at the start of every request, and disposed at the end of the request. Much like a simple `UnitOfWork` implementation. Now think of having a `Order` class (EF generated), which is going to be initialised. I pass the `ObjectContext` to be used trough a overloaded constructor.

```
var order = new Order(myObjectContext);
```

Then inside the `Order` class this instance is kept (private field). After I set some properties of this `Order` instance (using the same `ObjectContext`). I want to put this instance in the Users' session because a second webpage is needed to populate some information before the order is ready to be saved.

This is were I'm stuck, after the user submits the second webpage I retrieve the `Order` object from the session, set some more properties and hit `.SaveChanges()` on the `ObjectContext` references by the `Order` object. So the one that was made in the first request. I think this is required because during the first request (when the `Order` was created) some other entities are being added to one of the orders collection. So I have to use the same context again. The problem is that after hitting the `.SaveChanges()` the method returns no error or whatsoever, but the data is not saved in the database. Even the identity value does not change from zero. Nothing is being committed.

When I first try to add the object to the collection:

```
this._context.Order.AddObject(this);
this._context.SaveChanges();
```

Please note this code is within a method, placed in a partial Order class. This time, at the `.AddObject()` I get the message:

`An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.`

I tried to detach the `Order` object from it's original context and reattach it to the context made in the second request but of course this is not working since one of the `Order` properties is a collection of other entities, retrieved and added in the first request, thus with the first `ObjectContext`.

Probably I could overcome this issue by calling `.SaveChanges()` at the end of the first request. Then in the next request I would have to pull the order from the db with that request's `ObjectContext`. The thing is, I do not want to save the `Order` before the end of the second request.

To me it looks like the `ObjectContext` which is kept with the `Order` instance in the session needs a 'connection-refresh'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure I understand what you are trying to do but it seems that you want to make several changes to the Order object and only save it when all changes have been applied. Correct me if I am wrong but I take it that you are passing the ObjectContext as a parameter to the Order object and then putting the Order object in the session to embed the connection and maintain it to the next page?

This is probably where your entity object and the ObjectContext gets disconnected.

I suggest you take a look at the Self-Tracking Entity Generator - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx . Maybe this will help you - http://henrycomputerworld.blogspot.no/2012/01/save-temporary-data-with-entity.html

This should allow you to do as many postbacks as necessary and let the Order instance track its own changes. You should then be able to commit the changes on your single ObjectContext instance.

If this doesn´t help, maybe you can provide a little more code and explanation.

Comment: I think you got it perfectly right, I'm going to research the information you have provided. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you can figure it out. If this helped you, please remember to mark answer as correct :)

Comment: Altough I did not use your solution (instead I changed some of the apps design completely) it seems to be a working solution for my original problem. Therefore I mark your answer as correct.